# Javascript syntax to pass variables

Tags: javascript, flash

Still muddling my way through Javascript, I'm trying to pass the contents of variable *playnoyes* to the long line of code below to decide whether or not to autoplay the flash movie, but doing it as I have below, the resultant line of code has the variable in quotes and therefore the code doesn't execute it as expected. My question is, how can I pass the variable so that the resulting line of code doesn't have the quotes around the variable value.

Many thanks, and sorry for the noobness of the question.

```
var playnoyes='true';
var testtext = "<script type='text\/javascript'>AC_FL_RunContent ('codebase','http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0','width','320','height','220','id','HTIFLVPlayer','src','HTIFLVPlayer','flashvars','&MM_ComponentVersion=1&skinName=HTI_Skin&streamName=nigel&autoPlay=\""+playnoyes+"\"&autoRewind=true','quality','high','scale','noscale','name','HTIFLVPlayer','salign','lt','pluginspage','http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer','wmode','transparent','movie','HTIFLVPlayer');<\/script>";
alert (testtext);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because you are explicitly adding the quotes:

change

```
nigel&autoPlay=\""+playnoyes+"\"&autoRewind=true'
```

to

```
 nigel&autoPlay=" + playnoyes + "&autoRewind=true'
```

Comment: Many thanks. It actually needed single quotes around the + playnoyes + but then it worked fine thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var playnoyes='true';
var testtext = "<script type='text\/javascript'>AC_FL_RunContent ('codebase','http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0','width','320','height','220','id','HTIFLVPlayer','src','HTIFLVPlayer','flashvars','&MM_ComponentVersion=1&skinName=HTI_Skin&streamName=nigel&autoPlay="+playnoyes+"&autoRewind=true','quality','high','scale','noscale','name','HTIFLVPlayer','salign','lt','pluginspage','http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer','wmode','transparent','movie','HTIFLVPlayer');<\/script>";
alert (testtext);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the two '\"' on each side of the variable, no?